# jquery cycle and jcarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jquery-cycle

I've got a gallery setup with jquery cycle and jcarousel.
I generate thumbnails with php

```
<ul id="pager">
    <?php foreach ($thumbs as  $thumb) : ?>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo $thumb ?> </a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Now I create a carousel and append the pager to cycle

```
$('#pager').jcarousel({});
if ( $('#images').length > 0 ) {
     $('#images').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({ 
     fx:     'turnDown', 
     speed:  500, 
     timeout: 5000, 
     pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
     pager:  '#pager', 
     pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
         return '#pager li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
    } ,
    after: function(dir, id, el) {
        var w= $('.jcarousel-clip-horizontal').width();
        var i = $('.jcarousel-item-horizontal').width();
        var slide = $('#pager .activeSlide');
        if ( slide.position.left > w-i  ) {
            $('div.jcarousel-next').trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
  $('#pager a').mouseenter(function() { 
     $('#images').cycle('toggle'); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
     $('#images').cycle('toggle'); 
});
```

I got 7 elements in my pager visible and I want to trigger the scroll event for the next item thats not visible.

I tried to add an counter for the activeSlider using the jquery index() function but it got messy when hovering over pager item with the cursor.

Any advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use version 2 of cycle

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php

Comment: After many faild attempts to make this work I guess I;ll have to try the version 2 of cycle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found a solution to whis problem took me a while, probably can be done better but here's the code I use I think it's pretty straight forward

```
$('#pager').jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    wrap:'last',
});
if ( $('#images').length > 0 ) {
    $('#images').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({ 
        fx:     'turnDown', 
        speed:  500, 
        timeout: 5000, 
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
        pager:  '#pager', 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '#pager li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
        } 
        ,after: onBefore
    });
};

function onBefore(curr,next,opts) {
    var size = $('#pager li').size();
    var activeSlide = $('#pager .activeSlide');
    var position = activeSlide.offset();

    // get the position of the carousel clip container
    var container = $('.jcarousel-clip');
    var containerOff = container.offset();

    //first load 
    if(position!=null){
                    // get the information 
        var slideRigt = position.left + activeSlide.width();
        var containerRight = containerOff.left + container.width();
                    // slide is out ou bound on the right
            if ( slideRigt > containerRight ) {
                    $('div.jcarousel-next').trigger('click');
                }
                    // slide is out of bound on the left - rewind/wrap thumbnails to first item
                    else if ( position.left < containerOff.left ) {
                    $('div.jcarousel-next').trigger('click');
                };
    }
};
```

Hope this will be usefull to someone with the same problem. Still trying to figure out if theres a way to make this work with a wrap: 'circular' option for jcarousel.